# Add div on EMED Tag

Tags: shortcode, responsive, videos

For make Video EMBED in responsive mode i need to add a div before iframe like:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe width="600" height="338" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f5CcOq8UzkI?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

But when add with `[embed width="" height=""]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=/f5CcOq8UzkI[/embed]`

the result is:

```
<p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXX?feature=oembed" allowfullscreen="" height="113" frameborder="0" width="200"></iframe></p>
```

Now i have tried with:

```
function Oembed_youtube_no_title($html,$url,$args){
    $url_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($url_string, $id);
    if (isset($id['v'])) {
        return '<div class="embed-container"><iframe width="'.$args['width'].'" height="'.$args['height'].'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$id['v'].'?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter('oembed_result','Oembed_youtube_no_title',10,3);
```

but the result is always iframe, how to change the embed tag and add a div element? 
And why WordPress not suppor responsive Video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 'embed_oembed_html' to wrap that iframe inside the div.

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'Oembed_youtube_no_title', 99, 4);

function Oembed_youtube_no_title($html, $url, $attr, $post_id) {
  return '<div class="embed-container">' . $html . '</div>';
}
```

Didn't test please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: And with that you can add some CSS to make - for example - the embedded video responsive: 
`
.embed-container {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}`